# Best way to stress test a rails web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, web-applications, production, stress-testing

Are there any good (preferably free) tools out there?

Can they give accurate estimates that reflect production results when the app goes live?

Comment: Stress test usually means testing the whole stack of software that delivers the information and is not necessarily bounded to a language. Another term would be performance testing. And You may also want to try functional web testing tools to test the most paths. Want you want is quite large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not a free solution, but [webmetrics](http://www.webmetrics.com/) will get the job done. (As well as any website monitoring company in general). They give thorough reports on your web site's performance, and when you schedule load tests you can specify how much load you want to simulate (e.g. simulate 2000 users using my site at once).

I don't think it will break it down and tell you your CPU usage and such, as they stress your website from their servers.

Answer (score 10):

I would personally go with Apache Bench  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

It's free, straight forward to use and lightweight.

If you are looking for a something a little more robust then I think Apache JMeter might be worth looking at. http://jmeter.apache.org/. Again, it's free, a bit of a learning curve and has a GUI so a little heavier.

You might also want to take a look at this Q/A [Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/how-do-you-stress-test-a-web-application)

Answer (score 5):

WebLoad is open source:

http://www.webload.org/

Comment: After a Google search for Webload, I came upon this site: http://www.radview.com. They charge you a license fee and I couldn't find the open source link.

Comment: Yeah, not only is it not open source it's very expensive

Answer (score 4):

There's a good summary of tools [here](http://www.load-testing-tools.com/).

Comment: Oh man, but that stock photo on the link is awful!

Comment: i just checked it again and man...it seeed they never changed their design since 2004 but they're still updating it! there's a google +1 widget at the bottom @_@

Comment: that abomination is still there!

Answer (score 3):

Rails comes with performance testing built in: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html

Comment: Anyone swear by this over other API's?

Comment: This is not part of rails anymore, andwas moved to [rails-perftest gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-perftest).

Answer (score 2):

You can try Trample, it is load simulation tool [here](http://github.com/giraffesoft/trample/)

Comment: looks like trample is now at http://github.com/jamesgolick/trample

I've also heard of http://github.com/dbrady/tourbus

and of course jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize performance instead of just look at the numbers you might try Engulf. It's Open Source Software, distributed, and high-performance. http://engulf-project.org/#usage Disclaimer: It's a project I work on.