# Stress Testing in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, stress-testing

Can someone please point out the best tools for stress testing in Rails 4. I know that there are already some questions on this subject but the ones I managed to find all seemed outdated.

If someone could point me to a similar question that would be great also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've found outdated posts, the best way to get some fresh answers in would be to place a bounty on them. Duplicating questions over and over won't help visitors searching for the same thing find a better answer.

Comment: Ups, sorry! I will do that. Just starting to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 7):

Sendgrid recently came out with a pretty nice free solution that works for web or API endpoints.

Worked great for me:

https://loader.io

Answer (score 6):

Most performance testing tools will work just fine with Rails. I have used WebLOAD from [RadView](http://www.radview.com/) in the past.

Other relevant questions:

- [Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application?rq=1)
- [Best way to stress test a rails web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311925/best-way-to-stress-test-a-rails-web-app?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

[Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) works well for me with Rails. It is very configurable. You can configure some logical behavior, run parallel requests, add your dictionaries to randomize queries and more.

Finally after performing tests I run [Request Log Analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) to get internal Rails metrics. The analyzer works well also for production logs.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this gem [GasLoadTester](https://github.com/gastzars/gas_load_tester)

```
require 'gas_load_tester'
require 'rest-client'
simple_test = GasLoadTester::Test.new({client: 10000, time: 60})
simple_test.run(output: true, file_name: '/mytest/mysite_result') do
  RestClient.get("https://www.example.com", {})
end
```