# concurrent users can a Apache + PHP solution support

Tags: php, mysql, apache, lamp

How any concurrent users can a Apache + PHP solution support? Please don’t be bogged down by Mysql constraints – we are using LAP without M as we are storing around 2-8 PB at the back end.

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be answered in its current state.

Comment: Without more info this is impossible to say. What will be that average time between user requests? Does it do aggregations on the data? How much info on the pages? Do a test and extrapolate.

Comment: We are proposing a service layered architecture where the back end will be REST SERVICES being served by a combination of .NET and Java application- The PHP solution would fit in the App server component under Dynamic content.
The PHP layer would be CakePHP using jQuery for Ajax and would use XML RPC JSON API to make service calls to java runtime and .NET servers.
This way we will be able to achieve high performant service delivery backbone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test a site rigorously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558970/how-to-test-a-site-rigorously)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it out:

- [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool

As an alternative [Siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/) comes to mind.

Also see the answers to [How to test a site rigorously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558970/how-to-test-a-site-rigorously/2558996#2558996)

Answer (score 1):

> How any concurrent users

Ok, there's your first issue - HTTP is stateless, so your webserver can support an infinite numbers of users - as long as they don't actually submit any requests to the webserver. Really the limiting factor is the number of concurrent **connections** to the webserver. This is going to be determined by:

1) the frequency at which users make requests

2) the length of time it takes to service the request

3) the keepAlive duration

The first 2 will vary enormously from application to application, while the latter is something you can control - using keepalives will improve performance at the browser at the expense of hogging memory (and therefore slowing down) at the server. Using a keepalive of more than 2 seconds is probably a waste of time.

There are good books available on Apache performance tuning which will allow you to optimize the webserver for your application.

Of course, if you have a common data substrate, then there's nothing to stop you adding more webservers on top of the storage (unlimited horizontal scalability) - so it's the storage substrate which ultimately limits the capacity / performance of the system (until you look at tuning the code and storage). And you get the added benefit of improved resillience.

Certainly a fairly low end PC (2GHz CPU, 2Gb ram) should comfortably handle upwards of 500 current connections - particularly if you're running a database-centric application, then you'll also get more benefit out of adding servers rather than upgrading the CPU/RAM.

HTH

C.

Comment: We are proposing a service layered architecture where the back end will be REST SERVICES being served by a combination of .NET and Java application- The PHP solution would fit in the App server component under Dynamic content.
The PHP layer would be CakePHP using jQuery for Ajax and would use XML RPC JSON API to make service calls to java runtime and .NET servers.

Comment: This way we will be able to achieve high performant service delivery backbone.

The question that we have is –

•         How any concurrent users can a Apache + PHP solution support? Please don’t be bogged down by Mysql constraints – we are using LAP without M as we are storing around 2-8 PB at the back end.

•         How many users can nginx + PHP support

Assume that we will be using a standard medium Cloud hosted machine-  Linux Server Size (RAM / Disk)- 4096 MB / 160 GB.

Comment: A Pb DB and you're trying to make a solution fit onto a single hosted server! You've got bigger problems than worrying about which webserver software to use.