# Network traffic simulation test

Tags: performance, web, simulation, stress-testing, network-traffic

I've got a PHP site up and running, and the db is mysql. before launching the site, I would like to test the traffic handling. Now am assuming that there are soe softwares that would simulate the traffic and log the processes running on my site. Any recommendation of software I should use? the traffic doesn't have to be real, but nonetheless, I would like to generate a high traffic to investigate the threshold of the site. 
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Gatling https://github.com/excilys/gatling.

It's a stress tool written in Scala which aims at being more efficient and lighter than Jmeter.

Basically you record a scenario on your website and then run it 'n' times in parallel.

Here is the wiki for more infos https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Basic-Usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter:

- It's free.
- it's easy to Start with lot of documentation on its Website and on internet
- it has a proxy feature to easily create test plan from browser navigation
- It is easy to start up processes on other machines. It remote testing, can be done from GUI or console.
- The scripts can be written in beanshell, java, or any jsr223 language ( groovy, Javascript, scala, jexl ...)
- it has a lot of built- in samplers and thanks to its plugin architecture it's very Easy to add new ones or use any scripting engine to do what's missing
- it has great user mailing list
- it has very reactive support
- it's now a top Level Apache
- it can run thousands of users
- professional solutions exist to run it from cloud

...

See:

- [Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/how-do-you-stress-test-a-web-application)
- [Best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)
- [How do you test the performance of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738/how-do-you-test-the-performance-of-a-website)

Comment: And? So people aren't allowed opinions? Bizarre. He is asking for opinions.

Comment: I also have one and it was mine :-)