# Stressing the memory of linux server

Tags: bash, memory, centos, stress-testing

I used the stress command to stress the CPU of the Linux server(CentOS). Following is the command used.

```
sudo stress --cpu  4 --timeout 3600
```

Also I want to do the stress test for the Server memory using such a bash command. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548400/how-to-stress-test-server-memory-and-processor) is not supported with bash commands. I am aware of the tools that can be used to stress the memory as stated [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/stress-test-linux-unix-server-with-stress-ng/). But I want to write a bash script to do stressing.

Does memory stressing affect for virtual memory or only physical memory?

Comment: `Does memory stressing affect for virtual memory or only physical memory?` If this is your question, is this anyhow related to some bash script and that `stress` command?  Why mention it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory is when some disk space is allocated for this to be more RAM, but would be slower as you are using the hard drive. I would not stress test the virtual memory, if you cannot stop a stress test using the virtual memory, then i would disable virtual memory temporarily, and then after your stress test on the RAM, you can enable the virtual memory again.