# how can I create dummy traffic for testing?

Tags: linux, load, ip, packet, traffic

I need to create some traffic load on a linux machine in order to test some different packet forwarding schemes. Any easy way to have some dummy traffic?

Thanks.

Comment: Voting for ServerFault migration.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/how-do-you-stress-test-a-web-application

Comment: @Petar Minchev doesn't belong on the ServerFault IMHO

Comment: @ant - I think he doesn't even have an application. That's why I think it isn't about programming and voted for migration.

Comment: My application is written in Python, but does that matter? I need some traffic in the background, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

With a second host, you could use `nc` to simulate server/client transfer, e.g. send files from a bash for-loop to the other host. See the manpage for examples.