# Best testing application for php application testing

Tags: php, cakephp, testing

I have made an application by cakephp.Now I want to test it efficiency.Can any body suggest me which one is the best application for testing php application?JMeter is it the best?

Comment: Have look at [PHP info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info),under **Quality Assurance Tools** section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends upon what kind of testing you want to carry on.

If you are considering UI testing consider Selenium IDE

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

If you are considering testing your php code consider PHPUnit

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/

If you are planning load testing consider Jmeter

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Or

http://gatling-tool.org/

Also See this.
[Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application)

Comment: I need load testing.Thanks for your valuable answers.

Comment: @MarkBaker You can edit the answer describing some key features of `gatling` if you feel so.

Comment: An answer detailing all testing tools could get quite long, there's also tools such as Behat and Codeception for application testing; but as OP commented specifically about load testing in his comment on your answer, I just added it as another comment