# Web site stress test with Perl

Tags: perl, testing, stress-testing

What is the best way to test a site with Perl? How can I emulate a lot of connections to check how my script works on heavy load? Maybe there is a nice module on CPAN?

I am not interested in testing for dead links or 404 errors, only in work speed.

Comment: Whatever you do, be careful of making too many requests; depending on how your site is hosted, you might get blacklisted as a denial-of-service attacker.

Comment: Thanks, I am experimenting on my own server:)

Comment: Is there a key script on your web site that you are concerned with?  Perhaps you can stress-test it in isolation?

Comment: I need a solution to test as you say 'key' pages and 'key' scripts. I am trying to understand what solutions work faster than others, and I need to do it with heavy load emulation. Yes, something like a stress-test

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application

Comment: I am looking for something like that, but it would be better to be on Perl, or it can be a program for Linux which can be started from shell. It can be much simpler than JMeter, but if there will be no more sujjestions I think I will use JMeter:)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know of any Perl specific ones, but when I googled "stress test with perl" (without the quotes) a few promising links came up.  Haven't tried them though...

Comment: I've found a Prima::Stress module. But it has no normal documentation and even no normal description:) P.S. I've viewed some links for stress test with perl, but most of them are pretty old

Comment: Local testing is still not production testing.  This is key, I have often run tests locally that failed rather quickly under load and real sized database.  So be sure have a deployment test plan too.

Comment: I have written these before so I can help you but it seems pretty straight forward for example:
`code`
my @urls ;
while($in=<>) {
 push @urls,$in ;
$start=time();
for (i=0;i++; i< 99999999) {
 use LWP::Simple;
   my $content = get $url;
 die if (/error/ ~= $content) ;  
 ##  Decide if you want to look at anything else
}
$stop=time() ;

## Write a report

Answer (score 0):

I have written these before so I can help you but it seems pretty straight forward for example:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my @urls ;
while($in=<>) {
push @urls,$in ;
$start=time();
for (i=0;i++; i< 99999999) {
    use LWP::Simple;
    my $content = get $url;
    die if (/error/ ~= $content) ;  
##  Decide if you want to look at anything else
}


$stop=time() ;

## Write a report
```