# Simulating high load on a php app

Tags: performance, load, simulation, scalability

I want to simulate high traffic load on my web app in the localhost. I found lots of simulators for java and python but none for PHP. Does somebody know such (open-source) simulators to help develop my application?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application

Comment: you could try apache benchmark, not mentioned in the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a load tester "for PHP. Any load tester like apache bench, siege etc will simulate your desired request/connection rates and probably do a better job than anything written in PHP.