# ASP.NET Web application performance testing

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, load-testing, stress-testing, perfmon

I need to stress test a web application to find if the problem lies in the front-end, middle-tier or back-end. So which of the Performance Monitor(perfmon) counters need to be monitored to conclude where the issue lies.
PS: I'm using URLStress to generate HTTP requests and using perfmon to monitor the performance

Comment: You might want to look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application?rq=1